# Python Browser Launching

Tags: python, browser

I am using Python 2.7 in order to perform a simple task of launching a browser, verify the header, and close the browser

```
#Launch the browser @ google
new = 0 
url = "http://www.google.com/"
webbrowser.open(url, new=new)

#Check for the header
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
conn.request("HEAD", "/")
r1 = conn.getresponse()

#Close the browser
os.system("taskkill /im iexplore.exe")
```

This just runs on an infinite loop in order to verify continuous connectivity. Ping check isn't sufficient for the amount of traffic I need, or I would use that.

My problem is that if I do lose connectivity, the script freezes and I get addressinfo errors. How do I ignore this, or recognize it, kill the browser and keep the script running?

Sorry, if I'm not doing this right...it is my first post.

Comment: Why are you launching a browser for this?

Comment: Meanwhile, do you really want the script to kill all instances of Internet Explorer? Even if the user already had it open for other purposes? Or if the default browser is Firefox, so each time you call `webbrowser.open` it opens Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you actually need a browser here at all.

Meanwhile, the way you ignore or recognize errors is with a `try` statement. So:

```
while True:
    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com")
        conn.request("HEAD", "/")
        r1 = conn.getresponse()
        if not my_verify_response_func(r1):
            print('Headers are wrong!')
    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to check headers with {}'.format(e))
    time.sleep(60) # I doubt you want to run as fast as possible
```